# enum date trucate

Tags: mysql, sql

tenho a seguinte `query`:

```
INSERT INTO celulas ( diaReunioes ) VALUES ( 'Terça' )
```

Está dando o seguinte erro:

```
Data Truncate for column 'diaReunioes' at row 1
```

Esse campo na tabela é:

```
  `diaReunioes` enum('Segunda',' Terça',' Quarta',' Quinta',' Sexta',' Sábado',' Domingo') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Segunda',
```

Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela linha da definição da coluna:

```
  `diaReunioes` enum('Segunda',' Terça',' Quarta',' Quinta',' Sexta',' Sábado',' Domingo') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Segunda',
```

Vejo que há espaços nas definições dos nomes a partir do valor ' Terça', creio que o erro esteja relacionado à essa definição. Como os valores enum no mysql são armazenados como um byte, ao informar 'Terça' sem o espaço contido na definição, o sgbd entende que não é o mesmo valor.

Sugiro fazer um teste tentando inserir ' Terça', só para confirmar a hipótese.
Caso positivo, sugiro verificar a definição da coluna e alterá-la.

Comment: era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Este erro é normalmente disparado quando o tamanho de caracteres do dado é maior que o tamanho definido do campo. Verifica o tamanho do campo `diasReunioes` se é inferior a 5 (no caso, 'Terça', que tem 5 caracteres)